# VLCKit Subtitle not showing

Tags: swift, libvlc, subtitle

I use VLCKit in swift, so i created customize video player view
and i have external subtitles for movies from links, i read files from server and convert it so string

```
do {
       let text = try NSString(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: self.subtitleUrl)!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

       self.mediaPlayer.openVideoSubTitlesFromFile(text as String)

   }catch {
      print("Error")
   }
```

and i called a function named "openVideoSubTitlesFromFile"
in player but not working
anyone can give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

This method (which will be deprecated in the next major release of VLCKit) does only accept local file paths, no remote URLs. You need to download the subtitles file, cache it locally and provide the path of the stored file to the method. Additionally, you may only use this method after playback started.